# How to export feather into Unity

Tags: modeling, export, particles, unity

I have a feather finished and I am trying to export it into Unity.

The problem is when I export I lose the hair particles but the quill remains. I recently converted the particle system in the modifier tab but it still poses the same problem.

Comment: Unity i meant to write

Comment: Do you know whether Unity handles particle systems the same way Blender does? If you open a new Blender instance, and import your feather into it, does the particle system behave the way you expect? I'm not yet convinced in this case that this is a Blender problem; it may be that both platforms (Blender and Unity) are behaving in compliance with their design specifications.

Comment: You cant export particle systems to other formats or applications, unless you apply them or convert them to actual geometry or objects.